# ITMS-90011: This bundle is invalid - The image file must be in the RGB colorspace

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I am submitting Application through Xcode Application validation successful but when submit to Appstore Then This error Occur.

**ITMS-90011: This bundle is invalid** - The image file must be in the RGB colorspace.

Anyone know what this error really means?

Comment: can you  add the entire error mesage that you are getting?

Comment: Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app. Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90011: This bundle is invalid - The image file must be in the RGB colorspace.

Best regards,

The App Store Team

Comment: Did anybody ever figure this out. I have thousands of images in my app all of which are RGB. I will try rebooting, Apple is so much like MS now, that is usually the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A file, probably an app Icon file is not using an RGB colorspace. There are a couple of ways you can tell this. I believe app icon files must be .png files. They cannot have a transparent background.

Use finder, right click on the .png file and look for More Info. The key is to NOT have an alpha channel. If you do, you will receive this message. If you are using Photoshop, like I am, the only Alpha Channel you can have on a png file, is a transparency channel. Your .png file must not be transparent or you will receive this error message.

[image]

When creating an image icon using Photoshop, it should look something like this:

[image]

Although, this is pretty much undocumented, I believe I received this error because I had a transparent background on a png file. I then converted my png to a jpg, which I saw on another Stackoverflow thread. That got rid of my alpha channel error but caused this error. I then went and created all of my original png files with no transparent alpha channel and the error went away.

I am pretty disappointed with the Apple error message, which of course comes in an email after your submission to test flight succeeds. I assume it was telling me, not to use a jpg image for app icons.